# Data as Text with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I have a data attribute and want the information stored in it to be loaded into a different div as a text. The attribute is working, but I have no clue how I can send it to my div immediately after page-load.

Code:

```js
$(".title").click(function(){
 var title = $(this).data("project");
 $(".project").text(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="project"></p>

<div class="projectTitle">
  <p class="title" data-project="projecttitle">
    click to get data
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want it to happen as soon as the page loads.  Can you put your function in ready()? something like:

```
$().ready(function() {
    var title = $("#title-id").data("project"); 
    $(".project").text(title);
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thanks for this. Its working. But do you know how i can make this dynamically? I want to use this in a slideshow and using this for my caption. In the moment only the first caption will be shown... Would be nice if you can help me here

Comment: @Dennis that depends on how your page works, if the title is dynamically updated by some other code, you can probably use the .change() event handler in place of .click().

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when I run it. https://jsfiddle.net/zs76ypue/

```
$(".title").click(function(){
    var title = $(this).data("project");
    $(".project").text(title);
});
```

Edit:

Ah, I see you want this not to happen on click but on page load. If so, the other answer has it right, use .ready().